# Read comma separated values from a text file in Java and find the maximum number from each line

Tags: java, java-io

I used the following code to read all the lines. Now as I understand it I should somehow parse the numbers from each line and apply a function to get the maximum value. The problem is I do not know how to go about it and I do not know what to search for in google. The problem is one of **unknown unknowns**. Some pointers would be helpful.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class KnowNotTest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Using Path.readAllLines()");
    try{
        List<String> fileData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("files\\b.txt"));
        fileData.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

The text file I am reading is as below:

```
10,11,12
2,13
33,22,1,1
1
```

And the expected output is:

```
12
13
33
1
```

Comment: Look at the `split()` function on `String` and the `Integer.parseInt()` function.

Comment: So you have the lines, maybe you should **split** then lines?  Loop through the result keeping tracks of the max.

Comment: After reading each line put that line in a string and use String.split() , it will return an array type, and then you can loop through that array and compare each element till you find the biggest.

Answer (score 2):

Without checking the input file is correct

```
readAllLines(Paths.get("/tmp/lines.txt")).stream()
        .mapToInt(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(","))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max().getAsInt())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

the previous one is the best one to do, not directly (there are three important *and decoupled* parts: read, compute and report) also, it open te door to process in a efficient, online, streaming way (`readAllLines` break it).

An imperative way is

```
for(String line: readAllLines(Paths.get("/tmp/lines.txt"))) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (String word : line.split(","))
        max = Math.max(max, Integer.parseInt(word));
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

but is coupled and not compose.

Comment: How on earth does this benefit the OP.  Do you even thinks he understands this?

Comment: The most important and best thing a teacher can do for his student is to make him think. If he is really interested, my answer will remain in his memory. And he will learn.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but on the other hand maybe he will just copy-pasta...

Comment: Maybe, but if he doesn't understand it, his teacher will point it out to him anyway. (I've updated anyway my answer, although it contains a copy/pasteable version...)

Comment: I clarify. The difficult expression forces you to understand and exercise your mind, the easy expression does not, because it is "trivially understandable" and your mind has not made any effort. My daughter is perfectly normal (she has no special ability) but at 10 years old and just playing she masters a non-native language (English) and algebra. The trick is to make her think. If you treat them like babies, they will be babies all their lives.

Answer (score 0):

Use **mapToXX** method of **stream api** :

```
public class KnowNotTest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Using Path.readAllLines()");
    try{
        List<String> fileData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("files\\b.txt"));
        
        System.out.println("Input: ");
            fileData.forEach(System.out::println);

            System.out.println("Output: ");
            fileData.stream()
                    .mapToLong(
                            s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(","))
                                    .mapToLong(Long::parseLong).max()
                                    .getAsLong()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```